# Derived Column Transformation conditions error

Tags: sql-server, ssis

[image]

I got the above error.

I am trying to accomplish below conditions.

```
a. If EpicLocationKey = RevenueLocationKey then output EpicLocationKey = EpicLocationKey
b. If RevenueLocationKey in (0,1) then output EpicLocationKey = EpicLocationKey
c. Else output EpicLocationKey = RevenueLocationkey

[EpicLocationKey] == [RevenueLocationKey] ? [EpicLocationKey] : [RevenueLocationKey] IN (0, -1) ? [EpicLocationKey] : [RevenueLocationKey]
```

I try to test out the first condition. It is showing the similar error messages
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Names in SSIS are case-sensitive.   It can't find `EpicLocationkey` probably because it's `EpicLocationKey` like you have it in the middle part of the expression.

Comment: It still showing the error, but first error is different. it seems like somewhere in the statement is not correct. thanks

Comment: Looks like you also have a typo in `[ReveueLocationKey]`

Comment: I forgot to edited the post. All the columns are in correct case. I try to test out the first condition, but it return the same error messages (see last screenshot).

Comment: In the new error message, it looks like you've accidentally lost some of your expression.   The error says your expression ends at `[EpicLocationKey]` so it's missing the colon `:` and everything after it that you had before.